# $2^3$ Factorial Design conducted in a Latin Square Design

Tags: anova, references, experiment-design, latin-square

When does the situation occur to conduct a $2^3$ Factorial Design  in a Latin Square Design?

What would be the procedure of analyzing data of a $2^3$ Factorial Design conducted in a Latin Square Design ?

I have tried to understand the topics but I have not got any online reference.